# Danted Socks Proxy with Authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication, socks, dante

I've been trying to set up a SOCKS proxy on linux with danted. I have the proxy working perfectly without authentication, but when I try adding in authentication with both `method: username` and `method: pam` I can't log in with any of the usernames or passwords that I set.

When using `method: pam` this is the configuration I use

```
logoutput: stderr /var/log/danted.log

/#Interfaces for listening on
internal: eth0 port=1080 #AP external interface
internal: eth0 port=53
external: eth0 #interface on AODV network

/#Auth Method
method: pam

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: error
}

/#Allow any connection
pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    command: connect udpassociate
    protocol: udp tcp
    log: error
    method: pam
    pamservicename: sockd
 }
```

But when I run `danted -d` I an authentication error about a bad username and password. My Pam configuration is

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/danted/sockd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

and usernames and passwords are created with `htpasswd -d` to force crypt().

I also tried it with `method: username` and i get the same issue with a `system password userauthentication failed`. I am testing these with the proxifier proxy checker and they always return bad username or password.

I am currently running it without any authentication so getting this issue fixed is quite important.

I created a new user called 'test' with password 'password' and this is the error I got

```
Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): setting fail delay 
Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): username is estt 
Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): user not found in password database
```

Comment: What does the pam log (/var/log/auth depending on your system) tell you?

Comment: @cornelinux I created a new user called 'test' with password 'password' and this is the error I got:
`Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): setting fail delay
Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): username is estt
Jul 12 14:45:07 ip-172-31-26-147 danted: pam_pwdfile(sockd:auth): user not found in password database`
The letters in the username are all there just in the wrong order!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue eventually by removing the version of dante I had installed via apt and replacing it with one I downloaded from the dante website and compiled from source. There must be a bug in the version in ubuntu's repositories.